# Creating XML nodes with SOAP and PHP

Tags: xml, soap, nodes

I need to generate a SOAP request which looks something like this:

```
<s11:Envelope xmlns:s11='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>
<s11:Body>

  <ns1:SaveQuote xmlns:ns1='http://domain.com/BDB/'>
     <ns1:ClientType></ns1:ClientType>

      <ns1:Claims>
        <ns1:ClaimHistory>
          <ns1:Nature></ns1:Nature>
        </ns1:ClaimHistory>
      </ns1:Claims>

   <ns1:Vehicles>
    <ns1:Vehicle>
      <ns1:Province></ns1:Province>
    </ns1:Vehicle>
  </ns1:Vehicles>

    </ns1:SaveQuote>
  </s11:Body>
 </s11:Envelope>
```

I have :

```
 $url  = 'http://somedomain.com/soapurl.asmx?WSDL';
   try {  

    $client = new SoapClient($url);
    $saveQuote = array('ClientType' => $clientType);
    $claims = array('Nature' => $Nature);
    $vehicles = array('Province' => $Province)

     $response = $client->__soapCall(
'SaveQuote', array('parameters' =>$saveQuote), 
'Claims', array('ClaimHistory' =>$claims), 
   'Vehicles', array('Vehicle' => $vehicles));


var_dump($response);
    } catch (Exception $SoapException) {                           
    printf('Errors:\n',$SoapException->__toString());
    return false;                              
   }
```

But this just generates an error.. How do I get the nodes to be correct within the request?

Answer (score 0):

You should use objects that match the required parameter types. To do so you can use a WSDL to php generator that will ease you the generation of each required class for each parameter type. It allows you to use the classmap SoapClient option so you'll also have a response as PHP objects, much easier that arrays...

I would advise you to look to [WsdlToPhp](https://github.com/mikaelcom/WsdlToPhp) or even to the website [WSDL to php](https://www.wsdltophp.com/)